# downloading a url is not working in ie 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, internet-explorer-11

I am downloading the Video by url getting from server. It is only working in Chrome not in IE.

this requirement is in reactjs application.
i tried some node plugin. but i could not be able to download video files on ie 11.

```js
var text = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($(this).data('event')));
//here text is url 
if (undefined === window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {

  var e = document.createElement('a');
  var href = text;
  e.setAttribute('href', href);

  document.body.appendChild(e);
  e.click();
  document.body.removeChild(e);
} else {
  var charCodeArr = new Array(text.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; ++i) {
    var charCode = text.charCodeAt(i);
    charCodeArr[i] = charCode;
  }
  var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(charCodeArr)], {
    type: 'flv/mp4'
  });
  window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'download.flv');
}
```

Comment: Blob doesn't work on a bunch of Browsers.

Comment: @PHPglue: Not any recent ones. IE11 supports it: http://caniuse.com/#search=blob

Comment: What debugging have you done? What research? "Not working" is not a useful problem description. What happens when you try? What errors do you get, if any?

Comment: Could it be a type issue? Just a guess. Try changing the type. Does IE11 deny flvs?

Comment: i was not getting any errors in console window

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: i was trying with some node plugins like download and download-file . and  in the above code i was able to download csv,txt,jpg files which are downloading properly but video files are not downloading properly, it is downloading some dummy file with 2 kb size which is not playing in any media player.